# Error 404 squirrelmail-1.4.22

Tags: php, linux, apache, squirrelmail

I am new to squirrelmail.  I am trying to configure a mail server on a linux machine which I installed apache, php, and dovecot.

I installed squirrelmail from the source code in /var/www/webmail/

I configured a virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName webmail.my.domain.com
  ServerAlias webmail
  DocumentRoot /var/www/webmail
  <Directory "/var/www/webmail">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I set the Domain under "Server Settings" in the config file to webmail.my.domain.com.

when I try to do a configtest.php in browser: webmail.my.domain.com/src/configtest.php

I get this error: **404 Not Found
The requested URL /src/configtest.php was not found on this server.**

I am not sure how to get past this error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `Note that in versions 1.5.0 and up, if you are accessing configtest.php from any place other than the machine where SquirrelMail is installed, you'll need to make sure $allow_remote_configtest is enabled in your configuration file to do so (or see "11. Tweaks" ==> "7. Allow remote configtest" in the configuration utility). If you do that, be sure to disable it again when you are finished.`

Comment: I am using squirrelmail-1.4.22, but thank you for that note. I will keep that in mind if I upgrade to a newer version in the future.

Comment: Than check that file is actually there and name is in the same registry. Btw, roundcube is much more interesting, although it does not have as many plugins.